# Excel: Trying to match a value from one list, to another and output the answer from the 2nd list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on an Excel workbook for my boss's garage.

We have 2 sheets:  One sheet has a list of names, License Plate Number, Dates, and Known Owners.  This sheet is called "Garage".  The other sheet is a list of the Names and License Plate Number they are attached to.

Garage looks something like this:

Name 1 | License Plate Number 1 | Date 1 | Known Owner 1
Name 2 | License Plate Number 2 | Date 2 | Known Owner 2

Known Owners looks something like this:

Name 1 | License Plate Number 1
Name 2 | License Plate Number 2

I am trying to get the "Garage" sheet's "Known Owner" column to output the "Name" column on the "Known Owners" Sheet if the license plate in "Garage" matches the license plate in "Known Owners".  Is there a way to do this with excel functions?

Comment: Without having read the details, this will be possible with "index()" in combination with "match(...,0)" function. If needed, use wildcards "*". See https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function.